# Apache Camel CXF SOAP WS WSDL

Tags: java, apache, soap, cxf

In my application I am trying to expose one soap web service and doing basic operations. This is what I have done:

1. Created Interface with soap operations as per JAX-WS standard. Added all needed annotations
2. in WEB.xml added

```xml
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>            
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webservices/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

3. created one route

   ```
   from uri="cxf:/myservice?serviceClass="x.x.x.myInterface&amp;dataFormat=PAYLOAD"
   ```

I am able to see the WSDL details in browser (`localhost:8080/pro/webservices/myservice?wsdl`), but if I hit the service using SOAP UI project my request is not coming through. I'm getting the below error in SOAP UI project:

```xml
<soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>org/apache/cxf/frontend/MethodDispatcher</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
```

If I use `dataFormat=MESSAGE` my service is invoked by SOAPUI and getting response. But my WSDL is not coming in browser. Please tell which dataFormat i have to use in cxf component.

Answer (score 0):

It jar issue. After using latest Jar it is working fine